# Listen to body attach event

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a script which will be included in `<head>` tag of an HTML page.
It is supposed to add a special marker `<div>` in body and attach a listener on it before any other script in body is executed.

I cannot consume `DOMContentLoaded` event as it will be fired after all scripts have been loaded and executed.

If there a way I can get an event as soon as `<body>` is appended to document, my job is done.

Comment: May you post an [mcve] of your issue?

Comment: use promises .then, .then, when the first function get executed it will  do .then, something like callback

Comment: I just updated my post. I'm writing a library which will be included by developer in his website. Sorry for the confusion.